# A Good demo app for Intellitrace

Tags: demo, intellitrace

I want to demo intellitrace.  But all of my simple apps end up not having the methods instrumented (despite me setting the most complete "tracing" I can).

Does anyone know of a good demo app for intellitrace?  (or a good idea of one?)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Will an application where the exception originates from a lower layer but somehow got hidden along the way and subsequently not propagated to the user fit your purpose?

Answer (score 0):

The MSDN article that introduced intellitrace has an attached code sample.
Enjoy:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/ee336126.aspx